# Highcharts chart click event fired on click of the reset zoom button (bug?)

Tags: highcharts

I have a click event on the chart, but if you use the zoom and want to reset the zoom, the click event is also fired.

I've the following chart settings:

```
$('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'line',
            marginRight: 130,
            marginBottom: 25,
            zoomType: 'x',
            events: {
                click: function (event) {
                    alert('chart click!');
                }
            }
        }...
```

see working example: http://jsfiddle.net/2Y3ah/

Well this looks like a bug or if it's as designed how to block the click event if the reset zoom button is clicked.

Comment: Found a quick work around to set the position of the reset button above the plot area.

Answer (score 5):

A dirty way can be to look at the srcElement

for example test the following (check if firstChild not null ...)

```
event.srcElement.firstChild.data === "Reset zoom"
```

Comment: as well as event.srcElement.textContent == "Reset zoom"

Answer (score 1):

You can recognise if button is clicked, by event.target 
http://jsfiddle.net/2Y3ah/3/

```
 if(!($(event.target)[0].textContent))
                        alert('chart click!');
```

http://api.jquery.com/event.target/

Answer (score 1):

This is the ultimate solution. Just set the following config to the Chart:

```
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            resetZoomButton: {
                relativeTo: 'chart'
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: This is more a work-around than a solution: if the button hovers the plot area the problem still occurs: [http://jsfiddle.net/3rLxr0ee/](http://jsfiddle.net/3rLxr0ee/)